# sys/stat S_ISDIR(m) with struct dirent

Tags: c++, c, systems-programming

I want to check to see if a file is a directory, link, or just a regular file. I loop through the directory and save each file as `struct dirent *`. I try to pass `d_ino` to `S_ISDIR(m)`, `S_ISLINK(m)`, or `S_ISREG(m)` and regardless of the file, I will not get a positive result. So my question is: how do I use `S_ISDIR(m)` with `struct dirent`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you read a directory using [`readdir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir), the file type is stored in the `d_type` member variable of each `struct dirent` you receive, not the `d_ino` member.  You rarely will care about the inode number.

However, not all implementations will have valid data for the `d_type` member, so you may need to call [`stat(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat) or [`lstat(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lstat) on each file to determine its file type (use `lstat` if you're interested in symbolic links, or use `stat` if you're interested in the targets of symbolic links) and then examine the `st_mode` member using the `S_IS***` macros.

A typical directory iteration might look like this:

```
// Error checking omitted for expository purposes
DIR *dir = opendir(dir_to_read);
struct dirent *entry;

while((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
    struct stat st;
    char filename[512];
    snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s/%s", dir_to_read, entry->d_name);
    lstat(filename, &st);

    if(S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
    {
        // This directory entry is another directory
    }
    else if(S_ISLINK(st.st_mode))
    {
        // This entry is a symbolic link
    }
    else if(S_ISREG(st.st_mode))
    {
        // This entry is a regular file
    }
    // etc.
}

closedir(dir);
```

Comment: The `S_IS*` macros cannot be used directly with d_type. They're offset by 12 bits from one another on most systems I've seen. You have to use the `IFTODT` and `DTTOIF` macros (nonstandard, or just compare directly against the `DT_*` macro values.

Comment: There is no the "d_type" field on Solaris ;-)

Comment: BTW: That stuff even works with Windows using Cygwin (and NetBeans, in my case).

Answer (score 0):

S_ISDIR(m), S_ISLINK(m) is to be used against `struct stat.st_mode`, and not `struct dirent`. eg:

```
struct stat sb;
...
stat ("/", &sb);
printf ("%d", S_ISDIR (sb.st_mode));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use the S_IS* macros with struct dirent members, as stated above. However you don't need to since the member d_type already has that info for you. You can directly test it like this:

```
struct dirent someDirEnt;
... //stuff get it filled out
if(someDirEnt.d_type==DT_LNK)
...//whatever you link
```

In particular the d_type member may contain:

> ```
>    DT_BLK      This is a block device.
>    DT_CHR      This is a character device.
>    DT_DIR      This is a directory.
>    DT_FIFO     This is a named pipe (FIFO).
>    DT_LNK      This is a symbolic link.
>    DT_REG      This is a regular file.
>    DT_SOCK     This is a UNIX domain socket.
>    DT_UNKNOWN  The file type is unknown.
> ```